# Getting error while opeing ".cfg" file with the XGCONF tool

Tags: rtos, ti-ccstudio, eclipse

I got some strange errors in ccs.

I'm using a cc2640r2f IC and downloaded there simple_periphal_oad_on_chip from resource explorer. Whenever I open the *.cfg* file with the XGCONF tool I get an error As:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type Can't find import file: 'common/cc26xx/kernel/cc2640/config/cc2640_r2_csdk.cfg'.

Of course I checked the location and the "cc2640_r2_csdk.cfg" is at the location it says it is not.

If I choose a different tool to open the cfg file like xdc script editor then no errors are displayed.

- My first question what exactly is the XGCONF doing differently than the xdc script editor when it opens the cfg file?
- What are some starting points to do to find out what is causing this?

Comment: I began to read your question. ... I assumed that the `iam` is a typo, but when i got to the `ccs,iam`, I stopped reading. ... If you cannot bother to post a question that uses a somewhat proper sentence structure, then I will not bother to read it.

Comment: I wrote "opeing" instead of "opening". Please correct it.